# how to convert MID file to wav file?

Tags: iphone

I want to play background music in my game application using AVAudio player.I am using .MDI file.This file is not playing in AVAudio player.So i want to convert this .MDi file to wav file.IS it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming you're trying to convert it on a Mac the following steps will result in a MIDI file being converted to a WAV file (should also work on PC's and Linux O/S's).

1. Download and install [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
2. Once Audacity has been downloaded and installed (launch Audacity)
3. Open your MIDI file that you want to convert to WAV (don't play it yet though). Quicktime Player should be fine
4. Back in the Audacity application, press the Record button (red circle), you should see a recording take place, play your MIDI file that's opened in the Quicktime Player.
5. Once the MIDI file in Quicktime Player has stopped, press the stop button (yellow square)
6. Go to File -> Export As WAV... And save your file
7. That's it!!! You should now have file that is in a WAV file format :-)

If you have problems with the following just post a comment, and I'll try and help you out.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TiMidity++](http://timidity.sourceforge.net/)